# Gaussian distribution with Gamma variance

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian, gamma-distribution

I am using a hierarchical Bayesian model. In one part of it, I have a normal distribution with mean zero and a variance sampled from a Gamma distribution for some hyper-parameters $a_0$ and $a_1$:

$$p(x|\alpha)  \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\alpha) $$
$$p(\alpha|a_0,a_1)  \sim \text{Gam}(a_0,a_1)$$

Does the distribution of $x$ after integrating $\alpha$ out, i.e., $p(x|a_0,a_1)$, have a closed-form expression?

Comment: The well-known conjugate prior in this case is inverse gamma, so for inverse gamma it does has a close form. For gamma distribution it may in terms of Bessel function, see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5Eae%5E(-1%2Fx-x)+from+x+%3D+0+to+x+%3D+%2Binfty